# custom function is not working in mysql query how can i get it working?

Tags: php, sql

i encountered a sql query while working on a project which is previously working well on php 5.Now migrating it to php 7, There is a kind of custom function in the query which uses 4 parameters, two of which are passed locally by php variable but other parameters are passed by referring to table column names.At my level of knowledge i am not able to guess how is it working on php 5 live web site. You can see that there is a calculateDistance() function used in the sql query.

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION mydb_db.calculateDistance does not exist in ....


$String_SQL = "Insert into pogopro_search_engine_result_cache(user_id,project_id,merchant_id,match_items,business_name,certifications,has_work_permit,has_promotion,service_rating_count,gps_lat,gps_long,service_rating_amount,distance,logo_url) "
          ."Select ".$user_id." as user_id,".$project_id." as project_id,a.merchant_id,count(a.pro_service_category_id) as match_items,b.business_name,b.certifications,b.has_work_permit,b.has_promotion,b.service_rating_count,b.business_gps_lat as gps_lat,b.business_gps_long as gps_long,b.service_rating_amount,calculateDistance(".$gps_lat.",".$gps_long.",b.business_gps_lat,b.business_gps_long) as distance,b.logo_url "
          ."From pogopro_pro_offer_services a,rv_merchants b ";
    if ($service_language>0)
        $String_SQL .=",pogopro_speak_languages c ";
        $String_SQL .="Where a.merchant_id = b.id and a.merchant_id <> ".$merchant_id_of_user." " 
          //."AND pro_service_category_id in (".$service_category_code.") "
          ."AND id_service_category in (".$service_category_code.") "      
          ."AND (b.service_rating_amount/b.service_rating_count>=".$service_rating_start.") ";
   if ($service_language>0)
        $String_SQL .="AND c.merchant_id = a.merchant_id AND c.language_id = ".$service_language." "; 
    #$String_SQL .= "AND b.business_city = '".$target_city."' " 
    $String_SQL .="AND calculateDistance(".$gps_lat.",".$gps_long.",b.business_gps_lat,b.business_gps_long) <=".$distance_from_range." "
                ."AND calculateDistance(".$gps_lat.",".$gps_long.",b.business_gps_lat,b.business_gps_long) <= b.service_distance_range "
                ."Group by a.merchant_id Order By count(a.pro_service_category_id) DESC, a.merchant_id"; 
    //echo $String_SQL;
    $status = $this->db_conn->query($String_SQL);
```

Comment: It's right there in the error message `FUNCTION mydb_db.calculateDistance does not exist in ....`

Comment: could you tell me that, is it possible to call a custom function eg. php function in the query the way its mentioned in the query? and reffering two cdb table column values in as parameters?

Comment: `calculateDistance()` is a PHP function? Theoretically you could call it from the query, but that would be messy and prone to problems.